# Taking advantage of a group

Tags: single-word-requests

This is going to sound so stupid, but what word am I thinking of?

My mind is telling me that is sounds something like *platonize* and it means to take advantage of a certain group (racial minority, lower income families, etc.) and exploiting them in some way for personal gain.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be thinking of two separate words that sound like **Platonize**

> **Patronize**: to talk to (someone) in a way that shows that you believe you are more intelligent or better than other people

and

> **Plagiarize**: to steal and pass off (the ideas or words of another) as one's own :  use (another's production) without crediting the source

Otherwise, a word with a whole similar meaning might be:

> **Exploit**: to make use of meanly or unfairly for one's own advantage *eg. exploiting migrant farm workers*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider "[vampirize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vampirize):"

> **vampirize**: fig. : to drain the vital essence from; to plunder.

E.g. [Most Americans do not believe that the entire country is completely unfair, that a small minority is vampirizing the rest of us.](http://johnbatchelorshow.com/podcasts/2014/01/20/second-hour)

> [vampire](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vampire): a person who preys ruthlessly upon others.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vampire